# "Error in CharToDate(x)"

Tags: r, date, subset

I have a csv data set with a column that contains dates. After importing the data set to R, we need to subset the data set based on certain date range.

```
app1110 <- read.csv("file_11102015.csv")
app1110$appcom_date2 <- app1110$APPLICATION..COMPLETED..DATE
```

Then we tried 1)

```
app1110$appcom_date2 <- format(as.POSIXct(app1110$appcom_date2, format= "%m/%d/%Y"), format="%m/%d/%Y")
subset(app1110, as.Date(appcom_date2 < "12/30/2013"))
```

The error message:

> Error in as.Date.default(appcom_date2 < "12/30/2013") :    do not know
>   how to convert 'appcom_date2 < "12/30/2013"' to class “Date”

So how can I subset data based on the date range?

Comment: `appcom_date2 < "12/30/2013"` returns a logical vector. Calling `as.Date` on a logical vector doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your data, I suspect you need to change this:

```
as.Date(appcom_date2 < "12/30/2013")
```

to this:

```
appcom_date2  < as.Date("12/30/2013", "%M/%d/%Y")
```

Or better still:

`appcom_date2  < as.Date("2013-12-30")`

The key point being that you need to coerce the string (`"12/30/2013"`) to a `Date` object and *then* make the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the problem was comparing character to date types. This fixed it:

> app1110$appcom_date2 <- as.Date(app1110$appcom_date2,
>   format="%m/%d/%Y") subset(app1110,appcom_date2 < as.Date("2013-12-31")
>   & appcom_date2 > as.Date("2013-06-01"))

Got another question: when subsetting, I am using appcom_date2 variable as a criteria to set the period. **How do I also specify to exclude all NA values from that variable?**

Comment: `& !is.na(MyDateVariable)`